# is.na() not detecting an NA value

Tags: r, na

I am running this:

```
invalid <- calls %>%
  filter(is.na(Call.Date),
         is.na(`Was.this.call.cancelled?`) | `Was.this.call.cancelled?`=="No"
  )
```

I joined two different call lists together and want to catch any calls that are inaccurately entered in one of the excels.

It clearly says NA. Not "NA" or any of the other iterations of that. Its doesn't find it even when I change it to another column either.

I tried changing it to:

```
invalid <- calls %>%
  filter(!(Call.Date = NA),
         is.na(`Was.this.call.cancelled?`) | `Was.this.call.cancelled?`=="No"
  )
```

I also tried "NA" which was suggested on a separate thread.

This table is huge but I wanted to make sure you could see it properly.

```
calls <- data_frame(Call.ID = c("2024-00033364", "2024-00004349", 
"2024-00031862", "2024-00030927", "2024-00028117", "2024-00028044", 
"2024-00027885", "2024-00026433", "2024-00024393", "2024-00022877"
),Date.and.Time.Call.Received = structure(c(1706376780, 
    1704402840, 1706275680, 1706218980, 1706045460, 1706041500, 
    1706031540, 1705935480, 1705779960, 1705675440), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), `Was.this.call.cancelled?` = c("Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), 
    Minor.or.Adult = c(NA, "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
    "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", NA, NA), Sex = c("Female", "Male", 
    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", NA, 
    "Female"), Race = c("Unknown", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African-American", 
    "White/Caucasian", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Black/African-American", 
    "Unknown", "Unknown"), Date.of.Birth = c(NA, 24342, NA, NA, 
    NA, 25898, NA, NA, NA, NA), Location = c("231 not an address ", 
    "231 not an address ", "231 not an address", "231 not an address ", 
    "231 not an address ", "231 not an address ", "231 not an address ", 
    "231 not an address ", "231 not an address ", "231 not an address "
    ), Response.Staff.Name = c("Team Member 1 and Team member 2 ", 
    " Team Member 1 and Team member 2 ", " Team Member 1 and Team member 2 ", 
    " Team Member 1 and Team member 2 ", " Team Member 1 and Team member 2 ", 
    " Team Member 1 and Team member 2 ", " Team Member 1 and Team member 2 ", 
    " Team Member 1 and Team member 2", 
    " Team Member 1 and Team member 2", " Team Member 1 and Team member 2"
    ), Time.Arrived.on.Site = structure(c(1706376960, 1704403020, 
    1706276520, 1706219040, 1706046000, 1706041560, 1706032740, 
    1705935900, 1705780140, 1705676340), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), Time.call.closed.on.site = structure(c(1706377020, 
    1704403080, 1706276580, 1706219100, 1706046060, 1706041620, 
    1706032800, 1705935960, 1705780200, 1705676400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")),
    Updated.ID = c("2024-00033364", "2024-00004349", "2024-00031862", 
    "2024-00030927", "2024-00028117", "2024-00028044", "2024-00027885", 
    "2024-00026433", "2024-00024393", "2024-00022877"), Category = c("Attempted Suicide", 
    NA, "Mentally Ill", "Attempted Suicide", "Mentally Ill", 
    "Check the Well Being", "Attempted Suicide", "Mentally Ill", 
    "Unknown Trouble", "Unknown Trouble"), Address = c("123 Not an Address", 
    NA, "123 Not an Address ", "123 Not an Address ", 
    "123 Not an Address ", "123 Not an Address ", 
    "123 Not an Address ", "123 Not an Address ", 
    "123 Not an Address ", "123 Not an Address "
    ), Call.Date = structure(c(1706358421, NA, 1706257069, 1706199836, 
    1706026554, 1706023250, 1706013319, 1705917136, 1705762012, 
    1705655852), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Agency = c("Department Name Here", NA, "Department Name Here", 
    "Department Name Here", "Department Name Here", 
    " Department Name Here ", " Department Name Here ", 
    " Department Name Here ", " Department Name Here ", 
    " Department Name Here "), Dispositions = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Call.Source = c("Phone", NA, 
    "Phone", " Phone ", " Phone ", " Phone ", "Phone", " Phone ", "Staff Initiated", 
    "Phone"))
```

I want to return this in a separate dataframe so they know to edit this line in the system.

```
invalid <- data_frame(Call.ID = c("2024-00004349"
),Date.and.Time.Call.Received = structure(c(1704402840), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), `Was.this.call.cancelled?` = c("Yes"), 
    Minor.or.Adult = c( "Adult"), Sex = c( "Male"), Race = c("White/Caucasian"), Date.of.Birth = c(24342), Location = c( 
    "231 not an address "), Response.Staff.Name = c(" Team Member 1 and Team member 2"), Time.Arrived.on.Site = structure(c(1704403020), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), Time.call.closed.on.site = structure(c(
    1704403080), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")))
```

I am still learning and would appreciate the help. I've used this code several times and don't know why this wouldn't work for this on line.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064) use `dput()` instead.

Comment: Do you mean `is.na(Call.Date)` where you have `is.na(calls$Call.Date)`?

Comment: `is.na('Was.this.call.cancelled?')` is testing a string literal, it has nothing to do with any fields that may be in the frame. If it is actually a column name, then use backticks, as in `is.na(\`Was.this.call.cancelled?\`)`, similarly for the `=="NO"` test.

Comment: Kimmy, the dupe links discuss some of the differences between single quotes `'`, double quotes `"`, and backticks `\``; the first two are effectively synonymous in R but their use for selecting non-standard object/column names is limited; backticks are completely different but can always be used if desired and _must_ be used when the names are not normally "legal" R names. Nothing in your code here suggests we need the backticks at all. If I missed the point completely and removing the quotes does not solve your problem, @-ping me and we can sort through the difference. Good luck!

Comment: @r2evans The original question did use backticks, it was subsequently incorrectly edited by Jon, who replaced the backticks with quotes. I’ve reopened the question since the linked questions have nothing to do with the original question … however, in its current form it isn’t really answerable, lacking details.

Comment: @JonSpring Careful when editing an incorrectly formatted question: your edit changed the code’s meaning and made this into a completely different question. :-(

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph, my apologies Kimmy for not recognizing the backticks were somebody else's contribution.

Comment: Kimmy, I think we're back to the first request: please add a sample of your data, by [edit]ing your question and pasting the output from `dput(head(calls,10))` into a [code block], thank you.

Comment: My apologies for inadvertently muddying the waters in an attempt to make the code display as code.

Comment: @r2evans  I apologize for uploading my post in correctly. Its my first time posting here  because i genuinely couldn't figure it out. I also cant show more of the information than I have due to the nature of the information. I will try to create some dummy date to reproduce the issue...please hold :)

Comment: @jon thanks for trying to translate it. I have used the line of code to capture the NAs and they usually work but. I'm confused why this one wont pop out even though i clearly can see it in the viewer. I was hoping to get some reasons why that might happen for some lines and not others.

Comment: Kimmy, having data that is proprietary is fine and even "normal", I'm in a similar situation in that I cannot share most of my data if/when I ask questions. However ... that doesn't alleviate you from the responsibility of providing something representative of what you actually have. It is not our responsibility to know what the data looks like, and as long as you keep us in the dark, it is unlikely you'll get much more than conjecture.

Comment: _Make up data_ that looks somewhat like what you need, then test to make sure your code works the same on the sample data as it does on your real data. Then add to your sample data what you expect the results to be so that we have a guiding-light, so to speak. It doesn't matter if you use randomness or just `data.frame(Category=c("dog", "cat", "Cat", "groundhog"), ...)`. Bottom line, nobody can do this as well as you can.

Comment: @r2evans I tried to post it again. Let me know if this is better

Comment: That's much better, Kimmy, thank you! BTW, that's using `data_frame` which has been deprecated for a long time. It's not a problem, but ... what version of `dplyr` are you using? (Data provided in this format is absolutely the gold-standard, especially when we cannot be 100% certain of the class for each column. Thank you for doing that, it makes a huge difference!)

Comment: The row in `calls` that is identified in `invalid` indeed has `is.na(Call.Date)`, but its `\`Was.this.call.cancelled?\`` is `"Yes"`, so your initial `filter(..., \`Was.this.call.cancelled?\` == "No")` will not find it. Am I misunderstanding your intent?

Comment: @r2evans wait a minute...you might be onto something. That's so embarrassing. removing that fixed it. *facepalm*

Comment: lol, yes, I've been there so many times ... we stare at the data and the code for so long we stop seeing the details. Glad we finally worked through the issue, best of luck!

Comment: Since it appears to be have been a typo, that's perfectly fine, but your question is unlikely to stay open, and "answering" it is mostly just a poke in the eye with no real benefit to follow-on readers. Please come back with your next question(s), and I suggest that your current question is absolutely a "good question": usable, representative sample data, attempted code, and clear expectations.